# Regex to ignore data after staring point and endpoint

Tags: c#, regex, vb.net, uipath, uipath-studio

How do we remove or filter data using regex to remove data after an in between ? The starting point is the first date (date could be dynamic it is no the fixed) so for example 08/03/2020 and the endpoint is the last 3 in capslock string (which is also dynamic but only up to 3 characters in capital letters) for example TRU in the string below. And should ignore or remove all the data after that

Here is my current regex :

```
Regex.Match(text,"(?<=08/03/2020\s+)[\S\s]*?(?=TRU)").Value.Trim
```

But it aint dynamic .

This is to be remove since this is already after the 08/03/2020  and TRU.

Any idea how we can design a regex for this one ? thank you.
#data to be remove

```
  Processing
       Co-Applicant
       No inquiry records found."
```

#The String

```
"08/03/2020        NOVUS HOME                  Mortgage Company                                                     TRU
                     MORTGAGE
   07/08/2020        FACTUAL DATA                Mortgage Reporter                                                    XPN
   07/08/2020        FCTUALDATA                                                                                       EFX
   07/08/2020        NOVUS HOME                  Mortgage Company                                                     TRU
                     MORTGAGE
   07/07/2020        CROSSCOUNTRY                Mortgage Loan                                                        TRU
                     MORTGAG
   07/07/2020        FACTUAL DATA                Mortgage Reporter                                                    XPN
   07/07/2020        FCTUALDATA                                                                                       EFX
   05/21/2020        CAP ONE NA                  Bank Credit Card                                                     XPN
   05/21/2020        CAPITAL ONE                 Credit Card                                                          TRU
   05/21/2020        CAPITALONE                  Bank                                                                 EFX
   05/20/2020        CROSSCOUNTRY                Mortgage Loan                                                        TRU
                     MORTGAG
   05/20/2020        FACTUAL DATA                Mortgage Reporter                                                    XPN
   05/20/2020        FCTUALDATA                                                                                       EFX
   05/20/2020        FINGERHUT/WEBBANK           Finance Company                                                      XPN
   05/07/2020        EMS                                                                                              EFX
   05/07/2020        GROW FINANCIAL CREDI        Credit Bureau/Mortgage                                               TRU
                                                 Processing
   Co-Applicant
   No inquiry records found."
```

#Expected output

```
   "08/03/2020        NOVUS HOME                  Mortgage Company                                                     TRU
                         MORTGAGE
       07/08/2020        FACTUAL DATA                Mortgage Reporter                                                    XPN
       07/08/2020        FCTUALDATA                                                                                       EFX
       07/08/2020        NOVUS HOME                  Mortgage Company                                                     TRU
                         MORTGAGE
       07/07/2020        CROSSCOUNTRY                Mortgage Loan                                                        TRU
                         MORTGAG
       07/07/2020        FACTUAL DATA                Mortgage Reporter                                                    XPN
       07/07/2020        FCTUALDATA                                                                                       EFX
       05/21/2020        CAP ONE NA                  Bank Credit Card                                                     XPN
       05/21/2020        CAPITAL ONE                 Credit Card                                                          TRU
       05/21/2020        CAPITALONE                  Bank                                                                 EFX
       05/20/2020        CROSSCOUNTRY                Mortgage Loan                                                        TRU
                         MORTGAG
       05/20/2020        FACTUAL DATA                Mortgage Reporter                                                    XPN
       05/20/2020        FCTUALDATA                                                                                       EFX
       05/20/2020        FINGERHUT/WEBBANK           Finance Company                                                      XPN
       05/07/2020        EMS                                                                                              EFX
       05/07/2020        GROW FINANCIAL CREDI        Credit Bureau/Mortgage                                               TRU
```

Comment: I already have pointed out the solution I need , please remove that associated question

Comment: here is my current regex Regex.Match(text,"(?<=08/03/2020\s+)[\S\s]*?(?=TRU)").Value.Trim

Comment: Please add this detail to the question and explain what is wrong with it. You write that "*date could be dynamic*", why do you hardcode it in the pattern?

Comment: cause I dont know how to make it dynamic

Comment: I guess you want `(?ms)^\d{2}/\d{2}/\d{4}\s[\S\s]*TRU$` ([demo](https://regex101.com/r/73wsdP/3))

Comment: But date is dyamic and so it the last 3 characters

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew But what if the last 3 capital letters is not TRU ? like for example XPL , how do we make it dynamic Sir ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use

```
(?ms)\A(?:\d{2}/\d{2}/\d{2}(?:\d{2})?|−−DATE−−)\s.*\s\p{Lu}{3}$
```

See the [regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/73wsdP/12)

**Details**

- `(?ms)` - `RegexOptions.Multiline` (`^` matches line start and `$` matches line end positions now) and `RegexOptions.Singleline` (`.` now also matches newline chars) inline modifers
- `\A` - start of a string
- `(?:\d{2}/\d{2}/\d{2}(?:\d{2})?|−−DATE−−)` - two digits, `/`, two digits, `/` and two or four digits or `−−DATE−−` string
- `\s` - a whitespace
- `.*` - any zero or more chars, as many as possible
- `\s`  - a whitespace
- `[A-Z]{3}` - three uppercase ASCII letters (`\p{Lu}{3}` matches three uppercase letters from any language)
- `$` - end of a line.

Comment: Sir it did no longer work when the sample data is this

Comment: @MrDave Use `(?ms)^\d{2}/\d{2}/\d{2}(?:\d{2})?\s.*\s\p{Lu}{3}$` ([demo](https://regex101.com/r/73wsdP/8)).

Comment: some of the mode modifier is not supported sir I am using uipath , can you put or test that in this website sir https://regexr.com/ ?

Comment: @MrDave I won't use regexr, it is not user-friendly and less powerful than regex101 (only supports JavaScript and PCRE regex flavors). You are using the regex in UIPath that supports all the inline modifiers I am using in the answer.

Comment: By the way sir , I am so sorry , this is by the way the original format of data from the ouput https://regex101.com/r/73wsdP/9

Comment: that is the original spaces

Comment: @MrDave It is crucial to know 1) your input and 2) pattern requirements. Else, you can't even think of a solution, let alone the regex pattern. If you are sure that is your actual input, use `(?sm)\A−−DATE−−\s.*\s\p{Lu}{3}$` regex. See [this regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/73wsdP/10).

Comment: yes sir this is one of the format and the other one which you solve earlier is https://regex101.com/r/73wsdP/4 , I wanted to have a regex that could solve both hehe

Comment: This one https://regex101.com/r/73wsdP/4 and this one  https://regex101.com/r/73wsdP/10 without creating seperate regex for each since they could have the same pattern

Comment: @MrDave `(?ms)\A(?:\d{2}/\d{2}/\d{2}(?:\d{2})?|−−DATE−−)\s.*\s\p{Lu}{3}$` - [demo](https://regex101.com/r/73wsdP/12). I updated the answer.